# How to add elements dynamically on scrolling down to a particular position of a listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic list view with a dynamic adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454170/dynamic-list-view-with-a-dynamic-adapter)

I want to add items to my custom listview when the current scroll position of the listview is 10. Initially I will have 10 items in my listview. I want to add items to the listview when the user scrolls down to the position 10. How can I achieve this?