# Dynamic list view with a dynamic adapter

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, adapter

I want to create a dynamic listview which adds dynamic elements on scrolling to the end of the initial list. New items should be added everytime the scroll position reaches the end of previous list. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a scroll listener and override the `onscroll()`